# The source attachment does not contain the source for the file

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

В Eclipse в редакторе кода пытаюсь открыть из своего кода класс драйвера `org.postgresql.Driver`, но при этом получаю ошибку `"The source attachment does not contain the source for the file"`.

Код рабочий, класс подключен. `Project> Properties> Java Build Path> Libraries` содержит *jar-файл* драйвера и указывает на *source attachment*, путь к которому совпадает с путем к файлу драйвера.

Пробовал распаковывать *jar-файл* драйвера. Он действительно содержит нужный мне класс. Пробовал при появлении указанного сообщения нажимать кнопку *"Change attach source"* и указывать путь к *jar-файлу* (хотя он и так указан в открывающемся диалоге). Ничего не получается. Как же его открыть?

Comment: Этот .jar-файл, скорее всего, содержит только скомпилированный код (_.class_ файлы), и исходный код в нём не представлен. И почему вы не приняли (не отметили как правильный) ни один из ответов в ваших вопросах?

Comment: Я почему то думал, что eclipse его декомпилирует... Ответ отметил.

Comment: Декомпилированный код - это всё-таки не то же самое что исходники. Лучше, конечно, чем ничего, но всё же расчет идёт на полноценные исходники в, условно говоря, оригинальных _.java_ файлах.